# How to make GridView wrap its contents in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview

As the title of the post, I want to make a GridView which can wrap all of it's contents inside, it means if I have 3 items, each of them has 50px of height, so how to make a GridView contains these item that has 50*3=150px of height.
How to do that, please help me!

P/s: I want to do it by configuring XAML code, not in C# code, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer! Just set the height of the GridView to Auto by make it inside a Grid row.

```
                <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                      Margin="12,24">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="64" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Opacity=".8"
                          Background="White"
                          Height="64">
                        <Grid Margin="8">
                            <TextBlock Text="Students"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       FontSize="24" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Height="2"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              Background="#B0BEC5" />
                    </Grid>

                    <GridView Background="White"
                              Name="grvMatchGA"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              ItemTemplate="{ThemeResource groupItemTemplate}"
                              Opacity=".8"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    </GridView>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide height for gridview but it's children, it automatically takes the height equivalent to sum of children's height.

For example, you can do something like this-

`<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>`

Comment: The Grid does not have Orientation, at least in Windows Phone, guy :D

Comment: @iamatsundere181 My bad.. that is the problem by working on multiple languages at same time :p
Anyways I have edited the answer which is relevant to xaml grid view.. :)